# Adding a tag for CocosSharp?

Tags: feature-request, tags

So I started to dig into game developing and I was wondering why there is no tag for CocosSharp (`cocossharp`) available, already?

Cocos2d has a variety of tags for its ports, CocosSharp is a legit port from the Xamarin team using MonoGame to allow to use Cocos2D with C#.

I've not enough reputation to create the tag, but I think it should exist.

(On StackOverflow the tag is [already available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cocossharp))

Comment: If you have a question for it, specific that the tag is missing in the question, and someone with high enough rep will make it and add it your question. As Kevin van der Velden said, there is no purpose for a tag if there aren't any questions related to it.

Answer (score 5):

Because nobody needed one.

Tags only exist when there is a question tagged with them, deleting a tag is simply untagging it from all questions.

If you have a question about cocossharp for the site and can't tag questions just ask for it to be tagged (in a comment or in chat, or here if necessary) and someone with sufficient rep can edit it in.

Comment: Thanks, can you please add cocossharp tag here? https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/151655/display-shapes-of-box2d-in-cocossharp-for-testing-purposes
Some more questions regarding CocosSharp will follow up for sure ;)